# mypy reports errors on custom defined builtins

Tags: python, mypy

I'm using the `gettext` package to perform translations in the Python application. There's a custom Translation class which serves as a wrapper around strings and also defines a custom built-in function

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, message: str):
        self.message = message

    @classmethod
    def install(cls):
        import builtins
        builtins._ = cls

test = _('translate me')
```

When running mypy over this code I'm receiving the error

```
test.py: error: Name "_" is not defined
```

Is there a way to tell mypy abou the custom created built-in function?
In flake8 I was able to set a config with

```
[flake8]
builtins = _
```

Comment: No, mypy would not accept dynamically modifying the built-in namespace like that, as far as I known. I'm not sure . Personally, I would never do this

Comment: This is done by default by using the `gettext` module already so crating a new built-in is not that magical actually

Comment: I mean, I guess we can agree to disagree. IMO it is very magical, with very little advantage

Comment: That being said, since it is sort of the standard library, they should probably special-case it... Maybe open up an issue for mypy?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you need something as:

```
_: Type[Wrapper]

test = _('translate me')
```

Comment: Yeah but that will only work in that module, and presumably, the OP wants this to work *everywhere*

Comment: Yes the `_` is spread all over the place unfortunately, so including this in every file is very messy

Comment: Another solution: modify typeshed builtins pyi file adding _.